# Sliding Cart extension for Magento 2 enhances mini cart to the next level with responsive design and conversion oriented features

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, shopping-cart, mini-cart

There is already a full-fledged free extension available on Magento's marketplace and Github

Magento: https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-slidingcart.html

Github: https://github.com/ambab-infotech/slidingcart

Blog: https://roshanyadav007.wordpress.com/2020/01/24/sliding-cart-extension-for-magento-2-magento-2-3-x/

This might help someone.